# how is the date value formated in php

Tags: php, date, date-format

I'm new to php and trying to learn it. I created a database and one of my fields has the date value. I have tried many times to insert a date and keep getting errors. I need to figure out how to format a date. I have song table and inside the song is a year field that will display the year the song came out. my code is below as well as the error

```
DB::table('users')->delete();
    User::create(array(
        'name'     => 'Appetite for destruction',
        'Year' => '1987-11-11',
        
        
    ));
```

The error is below

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Year' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `Year`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Appetite for destruction, 1987-11-11, 2021-11-14
22:47:58, 2021-11-14 22:47:58))

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Year' in 'field list'

db:seed [--class [CLASS]] [--database [DATABASE]] [--force]

Comment: `DB::table('users')->delete();` --delete? Typo? BTW: use (PHP \DateTime format) "Y-m-d H:i:s" datetime format in databases.

Answer (score 0):

Review this: [PHP: DateTime::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

You can formate dates in PHP like this:

```php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // OUTPUT: 2000-01-01 00:00:00
```